# Storing AWS IoT to AWS DynamoDB without Duplication in Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I have successfully configured my AWS IoT thing with the IoT core console and created a rule to store the data from the thing in a DynamoDB table. The rule is working but i am getting multiple records for the same primary key value. How to avoid that, because i am using the dynamodb table for an android app?

Comment: A primary key is by definition unique, do you mean the partition key? How does the data look like? How does the rule look like? A couple more details would be very helpful :)

Comment: @Maurice yes i meant partition key only. I made a rule using the IOT core console only and it contains the only action of Storing data in the destination DynamoDB table. The table contains only two columns both of which are sent from the IOT device (one of which is the partition key, which remains the same, the other one keeps changing). i want the first value to remain same and second one to update in the table.

Comment: Is you other field defined as the RangeKey? can you please post your table definition

Answer (score 1):

A DynamoDB table cannot store duplicate PartitionKeys (HashKeys) unless there is also a RangeKey (SortKey) defined.

From your question I suspect the"other field" you are referring to is defined as your RangeKey. In this case the PartitionKey + RangeKey are unique, and the PartitionKey is not unique of it's own.

If you want a unique PartitionKey, remove the RangeKey from your table definition.